# Bookdown book vs chapter Appendix

Tags: r, rstudio, pdflatex, bookdown

I am rendering a book in `.pdf` with `bookdown` and I want to include several chapters.
`_bookdown.yml` looks like this:

```
book_filename: "my-Thesis"
before_chapter_script: "Script1.R" #Script1.R cleans memory (see Script1.R file)
rmd_files: ["index.Rmd", "01-intro.Rmd","02-C-quantity.Rmd","03-C-quality.Rmd","04-fine-roots.Rmd","05-aboveg-biom.Rmd","07-appendix.Rmd","08-definitions.Rmd","09-references.Rmd"]
delete_merged_file: true
```

`_output.yml` looks like this:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  lib_dir: assets
  split_by: "rmd"
  #config:
    #toolbar:
      #position: static
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  keep_tex: yes
  latex_engine: xelatex
  #citation_package: #harvard #biblatex
```

I would like to add an Appendix `07-Appendix.Rmd` at the end of the book which covers the whole book and shows up as a chapter, not as a subchapter of the "Above-ground..." chapter as shown in the following snapshot. This is also true for the `Definitions` and `References`chapters.
Any help is welcome many thanks.

[image]

Comment: You may want to check out https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html and search for "appendix"

Answer (score 0):

Start a new markdown page with the first line:

```
Appendix{-}
```

The {-} removes numbering. I find the rmd_files listing unnecessary. Attaching an image of a page and the resulting contents listing.

[image: Appendix in bookdown]